# Auto-hide Taskbar won't unhide

Tags: windows

When my taskbar hides it never comes back when I hover over it.  I can only get it back by pressing the "Windows" button on the keyboard.  Very annoying, but I can still use the system.

I have my taskbar on the left-side of my screen.  I have Windows XP.  I do not use Google Chrome.  Pressing F11 twice has no effect.  I read [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/019916b1-1018-4580-930b-f35d49ce50c5) post and it didn't seem to have any answers.

Anyone find a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe this is an OS bug which has made it into every Windows version since (at least) XP. It's also difficult to *reliably* reproduce but does affect numerous people according to Google, myself included, which is one of the reasons why I always end up disabling it shortly thereafter.

You could try one of the following, albeit neither is a *clean* nor permanent solution:

- Press the `Windows key` + `D` to minimize all open programs. Afterwards the taskbar *may* react normally again.
- Kill and restart Explorer via Task Manager. To restart Explorer from within Task Manager:
  `File -> New Task -> explorer.exe -> OK`

Answer (score 0):

When this happened to me, I dragged my start bar to the left of the screen and then back to the bottom of the screen. It has happened to me twice and it worked both times as a fix

Answer (score -1):

In order to get my auto-hidden taskbar to reappear in Windows 7 x64, I must position the mouse on the screen where the bottom section of the taskbar is (not sure what this area is called); it is where the icons appear in two vertical columns:

```
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
x
xx
xx
xx  <---------
xx
xx
```